# mockito test invocation into abstract executor

Tags: java, spring, mockito, hazelcast, executor

I am writing test on a legacy code, before refactoring it, this means that **I should not change that code**...
I am using Spring and Hazelcast, and my class is an Hazelcast Listener (if you don't know Hazelcast it does not matter, just be aware that I cannot change the firm of the method).

```
@Component
public class MyClass implements EntryAddedListener<String, MyEntry> {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier( "asyncExecutor" )
    private Executor executor;

    @Autowired
    private ClassToBeCalled classToBeCalled;

    @Override
    public void entryAdded( final EntryEvent<String, MyEntry> event ) {
        executor.execute( () -> {
                ...
                ...
                classToBeCalled.methodToBeCalled( event.getValue() );
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

I want to test that when `entryAdded` is called, then `execute` is invoked, and especially `methodToBeCalled` is invoked as well.
I am trying different approaches, but all of them are bumping into some mockito error. This is the last one:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClass {

    @Mock
    private Executor asyncExecutor;

    @Mock
    private ClassToBeCalled classToBeCalled;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Test
    public void entryListenerShouldInvokeTheClassToBeCalled(){
        // given
        EntryEvent entryEvent = mock(EntryEvent.class);
        MyEntry value = mock(MyEntry.class);
        when(entryEvent.getValue()).thenReturn(value);

        // here some of my tries, all commented because they don't work
        // doCallRealMethod().when(asyncExecutor).execute(any(Runnable.class));
        // when(executor.execute(any(Runnable.class))).thenCallRealMethod();

        // when
        myClass.entryAdded(entryEvent);

        // then
        verify(asyncExecutor, times(1)).execute(any(Runnable.class));
        verify(classToBeCalled, times(1)).methodToBeCalled(value);
    }
}
```

basically I cannot verify that the `methodToBeCalled` is called, because Executor is an abstract class. I cannot Spy it, I cannot call the real method. Also, the @Qualifier refers to an implementation in a library, which more or less is:

```
    @Bean(name = {"AsyncExecutor"})
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        ...
        ...
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Is using powermock an option?

Comment: yes, I think so.

Comment: Ofcourse it won't call the method you are using a mock. Instead of using a mock just inject a `SyncTaskExecutor` and use a mock for the `ClassToBeCalled`. Set the `SyncTaskExecutor` using the `ReflectionTestUtils` (as you stated you cannot change the code yet).

Comment: I think I can add a setter for the executor, it is not a big change, and it would help the test. But how to use the SyncTaskExecutor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use too many mocks. You are mocking the `Executor` but still expect that to behave as a regular `Executor` that obviously isn't going to work.

Instead use the `SyncTaskExecutor` which basically makes the call to `executor.execute` a synchronous call for your test and only mock the `ClassToBeCalled`.

Something like this, using the `ReflectionTestUtils` should do the trick.

```
public class MyClass {

    private Executor executor = new SyncTaskExector();
    private ClassToBeCalled classToBeCalled;

    private MyClass myClass;

    @Before
    public setup() {
       myClass = new MyClass();
       classToBeCalled = mock(ClassToBeCalled.class);
       RelfectionTestUtils.setField(myClass, "executor", executor);
       RelfectionTestUtils.setField(myClass, "classToBeCalled", classToBeCalled);
    }

    @Test
    public void entryListenerShouldInvokeTheClassToBeCalled(){
        // given
        EntryEvent entryEvent = mock(EntryEvent.class);
        MyEntry value = mock(MyEntry.class);
        when(entryEvent.getValue()).thenReturn(value);

        // when
        myClass.entryAdded(entryEvent);

        // then
        verify(classToBeCalled, times(1)).methodToBeCalled(value);
    }
}
```

The fact that the `methodToBeCalled` is being called is also the proof that the `execute` method got executed.

**HINT:** I would suggest changing it to use constructor based injection instead of field injection as that makes testing a lot easier.

```
@Component
public class MyClass implements EntryAddedListener<String, MyEntry> {

    private final Executor executor;
    private final ClassToBeCalled classToBeCalled;

    @Autowired
    public MyClass(@Qualifier("asyncExecutor") Executor executor, ClassToBeCalled classToBeCalled) {
        this.executor=executor;
        this.classToBeCalled=classToBeCalled;
    }
}
```

Now you can remove the `ReflectionTestUtils` and simply construct your object.

```
@Before
public void setup() {
   classToBeCalled = mock(ClassToBeCalled.class);
   myClass = new MyClass(executor, classToBeCalled);
}
```

Comment: changing the constructor based injection is in my plan already, I will!